# Is there a way to check if word appears in the DOM puppteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I was wondering if there is a way to check if there is a word in the whole DOM (Like CTRL+F)
via puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer , 
Seems like the way to go is evaluate the page via JS:

```
if (
  (
    document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText
  ).indexOf('Text') > -1
) {
  console.log("yes");
}
```